# Asp.net MVC 4 route failing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes, restsharp, azure-compute-emulator

I'm relatively new to MVC, but have successfully built out a standard user-driven CRUD site with it, so I have some of the basics down.  I started working on what I'd like to be a REST-ful api app built with MVC 4, and I am having what I'm sure is a rookie problem of getting a simple request to resolve to a controller in this new app.

On a simple test resource intended to support a POST operation, I'm getting 404's instead of 202's.  I've searched this site for solutions to route problems, tried a number of different combinations of hard-wired and parameterized route and default values, but haven't found anything yet for what I suspect must be an easy fix.

#### Update

I've also tried changing the route configuration setup (see Route Config #1 and #2 below) to use MapHttpRoute() instead of MapRoute().  This did not have any effect.

These are both web apps hosted in a single Azure web role, configured as two different sites listening on 2 different ports.  The problem I'm troubleshooting is on my local machine, so using the compute emulator with all of the urls starting with:

```
http://127.0.0.1:<port>/
```

For the client, I'm using RestSharp invoked from within the CRUD app.  Here is the class used for populating the body of the POST request I'm debugging:

### Data Class

```cs
public class TestData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsTrue { get; set; }
}
```

...here is the code used to serialize the data and convert to a string.  I understand that RestSharp will serialize for me, but I have other application-specific reasons that I'm doing the serialization myself, which I don't believe are relevant to the problem.  If that turns out to be relevant to the problem we can go there, but it isn't on my suspect list at the moment:

### Serialization Methods

```cs
    private XmlDocument Serialize<T>( T theData )
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer( theData.GetType() );
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ser.Serialize( stream, theData );
            stream.Flush();
            stream.Seek( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin );

            xml.Load( stream );
        }

        return xml;
    }

    private string GetStringFromXmlDocument( XmlDocument theDoc )
    {
        string result = null;

        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        using (var xmlTextWriter = XmlWriter.Create( stringWriter ))
        {
            theDoc.WriteTo( xmlTextWriter );
            xmlTextWriter.Flush();
            result = stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

...and here is the RestSharp client code that uses the data class and the above methods:

### RestSharp Client

```cs
XmlDocument theSerializedData = Serialize( new TestData
                                   {
                                       Date = DateTime.Now,
                                       IsTrue = false,
                                       Name = "Oscar"
                                   } );

string theDataString = GetStringFromXmlDocument(theSerializedData);

RestClient client = new RestClient("http://127.0.0.1:7080/rest/testing");

RestRequest request = new RestRequest( "tests", Method.POST );

request.AddParameter( "text/xml", theTestData, ParameterType.RequestBody );

IRestResponse response = client.Execute( request );

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    ; // Make a happy face
}
else
{
    ; // Make a sad face
}
```

...here are 2 of the route configurations I've tried:

### Route Config #1

```cs
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "RestTest",
        url: "rest/{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```

### Route Config #2

```cs
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "RestTest",
        routeTemplate: "rest/{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Testing", action = "Tests" }
            );
    }
```

...and here is the controller:

### Controller

```cs
public class TestingController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void Tests(TestData theData)
    {
        bool isTru = theData.IsTrue;
    }
}
```

...here is the raw request as captured from Fiddler (host name replaced with 127.0.0.1):

### Http Request

```
  POST http://127.0.0.1:7080/rest/testing/tests HTTP/1.1
  Accept: application/json, application/xml, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, text/xml
  User-Agent: RestSharp 104.1.0.0
  Content-Type: text/xml
  Host: 127.0.0.1:7080
  Content-Length: 243
  Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <TestData xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Name>Oscar</Name>
    <Date>2013-05-16T11:50:50.1270268-07:00</Date>
    <IsTrue>false</IsTrue>
  </TestData>
```

...and the gist of the 404 response from the service is:

### 404 Response

```
The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /rest/testing/tests

[HttpException]: The controller for path '/rest/testing/tests' was not found or does not implement IController.
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 1):

you would need to use the "routes.**MapHttpRoute**(" extension which is for registering Api routes and targets ApiControllers. Currently you are using MapRoute which is for MVC controllers.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that (see update).  This change had no effect, so I'm still at a loss for identifying the root cause.

Comment: according the error the request is not matching webapi routes and are falling through to Mvc routes...not sure why would this happen

Comment: Do you get a different call stack when the web api routes are handled?  Like, it's not handled by System.Web.Mvc?

Comment: Web API would return a 404 response if the route matched, but let's say there was no controller found with that name, or no controller found with the type implementing IHttpController or controller was found but no action was found on the controller etc...here the request is starting `rest/testing/tests` and since you have an api route with `rest/{controller}/{action}`, it should have matched...just to be sure, you indeed have `rest/{controller}/{action}` and not `api/{controller}/{action}`..right?

Comment: BTW, are your Web API routes registered before the MVC routes?

Comment: So, the web api routes are registered before the MVC routes.  I've since removed the other web api route so that mine is now the only one getting registered.  I also tried commenting out the call to register the MVC routes.  This had the effect of getting me a different 404 with no call stack, just a "File or Directory Not Found" message.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is specifically to do with running the rest app as a web role on the Azure compute emulator.  When I simply right-click on the app in VS and select View in Browser, or set it as the default project and run Debug->Start new Instance, I am able to invoke the rest API from the browser and get responses.  When I launch the app as a web role on the Azure compute emulator, I get 404's, as though none of the registered routes are actually registered.

I might post another, different, question related to the compute emulator and WebAPI apps, but at this point it doesn't appear that there is a problem with my code.  Could be configuration or some other system/environment problem with my Azure dev setup, or there's some defect in the compute emulator.